# Spring Boot MVC with JWT Token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, jwt

I am trying to build a web app with custom login page and access roles, but I wanna include JWT token also for the authentication and authorization.

Before including JWT, I configured security with access roles and ant matchers and custom login, I am able to access index view, when i wanna access "List of Students" i have to login with Admin credentials, when i wanna access "List of Subjects" i have to login with User credentials and it all works.

Now i wanna include JWT and i have all the JWT dependencies enabled, JwtRequest class, JwtResponse class, JwtUtil class and JwtRequestFilter. My security configuration is:

```
            csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/registration/**","/logout","/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/students/**").hasRole("Admin")
            .antMatchers("/subjects/**").hasAnyRole("User","Admin")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");
```

and i also included:

```
//                http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
//
//                http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

---

I have my CustomUserDetailsClass:

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private User user;


    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }



    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()
    {
        List<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Role role : roles)
        {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }
```

---

I have my CustomUserDetailsService:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if(user == null)
        {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found!");
        }

        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    }
```

I am not finding a solution to implement Token with my views. I can do it using postman with @RestController using a "/authenticate" method.

THanks in advance!

I wanna build an web app with user and admin. Users can access "list of subjects" and admin can access "list of students".

But im not being able to implement the JWT token with my WEb app

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to mess JWT in a server side application (that usually is the case for MVC)? What is your reason to do so?

Comment: In fact im applying for a job position and the task was to build a simple web app with login features and token implementation. Am i getting smthng wrong here? Does jwt implementation requires abother scenario?

Comment: Not sure how/why this makes sense but maybe you need something like https://github.com/stove99/springboot-thymeleaf-jwt

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of scenario in one of my projects, I uploaded it on GitHub so you can have a look, I fell it exactly what you want.
You just have to create a Authentication filter like in this project.

https://github.com/Parneet-Raghuvanshi/Spring-Boot-Basics

Do watch the **security** folder, it's all in there what you need.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
                .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/customer").hasRole("CUSTOMER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, SecurityConstants.TEST_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, SecurityConstants.VERIFICATION_EMAIL_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGNUP_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.PASSWORD_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.PASSWORD_RESET_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter())
                .addFilter(new JwtFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

this is the configure() function of my web security from same project, so that you can have an idea about the filters used here.

And feel free to ask any doubt from repo too. Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort but i think u didnt get my question. My problem is to implement the token using mvc , @Controller , with custom login page and many other pages. Am i missing smthng here? Or jwt can be used with this kind of apps?

Comment: Ohk, so you are making a simple spring web-app, I thought you were creating spring-boot, but if you want to create a simple login and signup then you can use spring-boot with thymeleaf to make JSP pages with spring-boot, so you can create both Rest-Controllers as well as Controllers.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what i did, i am using thymeleaf, i have created the custom login page, home page, student page, subject page, i have linked them all and configured the security for authentication and authorization based on roles. Now i just wanna put into play JWT . And thats what im not being able to do or i am just missing somehting, what do you think?

Comment: Ok so just go to https://github.com/Parneet-Raghuvanshi/Spring-Boot-Basics/tree/master/src/main/java/com/developer/mobileappws/security and you will find the JWT filter and then create a similar one and add it to your config file. Have you tried this way?

Comment: this is my config file :
http.csrf().disable()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/","/registration/**","/logout","/login").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/students/**").hasRole("Admin")
.antMatchers("/subjects/**").hasAnyRole("User","Admin")
.anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/login")
.and()
.logout()
.logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");             http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);  I also havae jwt util, request,response,filter